# REGEX for maximum 1 space between character ,no leading or trailing space

Tags: regex

I have regex which should match following

1. No leading or trailing space
2. {A-Z0-0}
3. Allow only maximum 1 space in between word
4. Total including space is 35 character

For example

```
(no space)ABC 123 450(no space) <-- Pass
(space)ABC 123 450(no space) <--Fail
(no space)ABC(space)(space)EFG(no space) <--Fail
```

I have try
`^\S{0,35}(?: \S+){0,35}$` but I am still not able to get rid of the leading space
Thanks``

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? The ability to use a zero-width positive lookahead will make this a lot easier.

Comment: What is the minimum number of character ?

Comment: iOS and Android

Comment: minimum number : 1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a sufficiently powerful regex engine, use a zero width look-ahead to check the total length (using `\w` here as a proxy for `[0-9a-zA-Z]` to make it easier to read here despite that including some unwanted characters):

```
^(?=.{1,35}$)((\w+ )*?\w+$)
```

Explanation

```
^            Match the start
(?=.{1,35}$) At this point, there are between 1 and 35 characters before the end
(\w+ )*?     Match zero or more (preferring less) repetitions of
             one or more alphanumerics followed by a single space
\w+          Match one or more alphanumerics
$            End of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
^(?!.*[ ]{2,})(?:\S[A-Z0-9 ]{0,33}\S)?$
```

As for an explanation, the `(?!.*[ ]{2,})` term is a negative lookahead, which asserts that the input does *not* contain two or more continuous spaces anywhere.  Then, the `(?:\S[A-Z0-9 ]{0,34})?` term matches a non space character, followed by 0 to 33 uppers or numbers, followed by another non space.  This covers a single character or more.  To cover the case of an empty input matching, we make this entire term optional using `?`.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for your replay 
But one character input should allow
Like A or 1

Comment: @BillyLei I fixed it.  Hard to write code right the first time.

Comment: Oh but this time the trailing space is problem
Like 
A AAA(space)